# Invalid mode to --compatible: mysql40

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have MYSQL 8.0.12 installed on my MacBook (the downloaded version). When I try to dump a compatible version of mysql40, I get the error `Invalid mode to --compatible: mysql40`. I'm 100% confident this is how it's done. Is it not? The mysql website [mentioned how to use it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible).

```
mysqldump -u root -p --compatible=mysql40 db_name > file.sql
```

> Invalid mode to --compatible: mysql40

Comment: Looks like they dropped that in 8.0 - there's no mention of mysql40 at your link: "The only permitted value for this option is ansi". Compare [the same docs for 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible).

Comment: Oh no! So basically I need to installed a lower version of mysql to achieve this? Bummer

Comment: Do you really need 4.0 compatibility? [5.0 was released in 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Milestones).

Comment: Come to think of it, I will update the old server's database 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the documentation for compatible in mysql 8:

```
--compatible=name
```

> Produce output that is more compatible with other database systems or
>   with older MySQL servers.
>
> **The only permitted value for this option is ansi**, which has the same meaning as the corresponding option for setting the server SQL
>   mode. See Section 5.1.10, “Server SQL Modes.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible

Comment: This will be very useful. Let me try this out then get back to you. Thanks